# How to filter in a schema in mogodb and redirect the same page with the data filetered

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am making a website and i need to filter product by type, i have a mongodb collection with id, name, price and type and the idea is to show all product and when the user clicks on rigth menu show the especified type in the same page, changing the content

this is for show all products

```
<% for(var i =0; i < listaProducto.length; i++) { %>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-b-50">
        <!-- Block2 -->
        <div class="block2">
            <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative block2-labelnew">
                <img src= " <%= listaProducto[i].ruta %> ">

                <div class="block2-overlay trans-0-4">
                    <a href="#" class="block2-btn-addwishlist hov-pointer trans-0-4">
                        <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart_alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart dis-none" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="block2-btn-addcart w-size1 trans-0-4">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <button class="flex-c-m size1 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">
                            Add to Cart
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="block2-txt p-t-20">
                <a href="product-detail.html" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5" id="nombreProducto">
                    <%= listaProducto[i].nombre %>
                </a>

                <span class="block2-price m-text6 p-r-5">
                        <%= listaProducto[i].precio %>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<% } %>
```

the right menu

```
<ul class="p-b-54">
    <li class="p-t-4">
        <a href="product" class="s-text13 active1">
            Ver Todo
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="p-t-4">
        <a href="product?<tipo=impresora>" class="s-text13 active1">
            Impresoras
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="p-t-4">
        <a href="producto-etiquetadoras.html" class="s-text13 active1">
            Etiquetadoras
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="p-t-4">
        <a href="producto-etiquetas-autoadhesivas.html" class="s-text13 active1">
            Etiquetas Autoadhesivas
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="p-t-4">
        <a href="producto-marquillas.html" class="s-text13 active1">
            Marquillas
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here is the get page

```
router.get('/product', async (req, res, next) => {
  const listaProducto = await prodcutos.find();
  res.render('product',{
    listaProducto
  });
});
```

and the schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const productSchema = new Schema({
  id: String,
  nombre: String,
  tipo: String,
  precio: String,
  ruta: String
});
var producto = module.exports = mongoose.model('products', productSchema);
```

i want to when the user click in a list item in the rigth menu show the products of that type in the same page changing the content (could be with the for )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it, was only make another get in the routes and change the href like this (also i add a pagination and its the reason to use :page)

```
router.get('/product/type/:tipo/:page', async (req, res, next) => {
  const tipo = req.params.tipo;
  let perPage = 6;
  let page = req.params.page || 1;
  productos.find({ "tipo": tipo })
  .skip((perPage*page)-perPage)
  .limit(perPage)
  .exec((err, listaProducto) =>{
    productos.find({ "tipo": tipo }).count((err, count) =>{
      if(err) return next(err);
      res.render('product',{
       listaProducto,
       current : page,
       pages : Math.ceil(count / perPage),
       total: count,
       typeIn: tipo
      });
    })
  })
});
```

and the rigth menu

```
<ul class="p-b-54">
                        <li class="p-t-4">
                            <a href="/product/1" class="s-text13 active1"> 
                                Ver Todo
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="p-t-4">
                            <a href="/product/type/impresora/1" class="s-text13 active1">  
                                Impresoras
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="p-t-4">
                            <a href="/product/type/etiquetadora/1" class="s-text13 active1">
                                Etiquetadoras
                            </a>
                        </li> 

                        <li class="p-t-4">
                            <a href="/product/type/etiqueta/1" class="s-text13 active1">
                                Etiquetas Autoadhesivas
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="p-t-4">
                            <a href="/product/type/marquilla/1" class="s-text13 active1">
                                Marquillas
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```